# Google Play Leaderboard service

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

i want to increase and decrease my score

```
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);
```

using that way makes me only increase my score

Answer (score 0):

**For fetch previous score:**

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.your_leaderboard_id), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(final Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult loadPlayerScoreResult) {
            mPoints = loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore();

    }
});
```

}

**For Increase:**

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "LEADERBOARD_ID",loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()+ score);
```

**For Decrease:**

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "LEADERBOARD_ID",loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()- score);
```